# C++11 Range-based for-loop efficiency "const auto &i" versus "auto i"

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, auto

In C++11, I can iterate over some container like so:

```
for(auto i : vec){
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

But I know that this needlessly - *needlessly*, since I only need to *print* the values of `vec` - makes a copy of (**EDIT**:  each element of) `vec`, so instead I could do:

```
for(auto &i : vec){
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

But I want to make sure that the values of `vec` are never modified and abide by const-correctness, so I can do:

```
for(const auto &i : vec){
   std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

So my question is:  If I only need to *look* at the values of some container, wouldn't the very last loop (`const auto &i`) always be preferred due to the increased effieciency of not having an extra copy of (**EDIT**:  each element of) `vec`?

I have a program that I'm developing in which I'm considering making this change throughout, since efficiency is critical in it (the reason I'm using C++ in the fist place).

Comment: Yes, if you only need read access to an argument, it should be through `auto const&` to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Comment: The "const" keyword isn't making your code any faster though...

Comment: `for (auto i : vec)` doesn't make an extra copy of the entire `vec`, it copies each _element_ of `vec` into `i`.

Comment: @Casey I see.  So upon each new iteration, the previous copy is deleted, right?

Comment: @user2052561 Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user2052561 - not deleted, but destroyed.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Yes. The same reason if you only ever read an argument you make the parameter `const&`.

```
T        // I'm copying this
T&       // I'm modifying this
const T& // I'm reading this
```

Those are your "defaults". When `T` is a fundamental type (built-in), though, you generally just revert to `const T` (no reference) for reading, because a copy is cheaper than aliasing.

---

> I have a program that I'm developing in which I'm considering making this change throughout, since efficiency is critical in it

1. Don't make blind sweeping changes. A working program is better than a fast but broken program.
2. How you iterate through your loops probably won't make much of a difference; you're looping for a reason, aren't you? The body of your loop will much more likely be the culprit.
3. If efficiency is critical, you want to use a **profiler** to find which parts of your program are *actually* slow, rather than guess at parts that *might* be slow. See #2 for why your guess may be wrong.

Comment: "copy is cheaper than aliasing" only with most fundamental types, besides move semantics can't been used in the OP's situation and since it T can be any type, a reference would be the right choice.

Comment: "*"copy is cheaper than aliasing" only with most fundamental types*" Which is why the first half of that sentence is dedicated to saying it applies to fundamental types...? Obviously if you don't know the type, you use the general case.

Comment: @Tim: No worries, it's good to mention the general case when the type may not be readily known.

Comment: Why would the compiler generate different code for for example "int" and "const int &" in a range-loop ?

It makes a difference when passing args to a function, but in a range-loop the compiler has everything it needs to optimize the hell out of it.

I tried disassembling a few range-loops and the generated code was the same. Same for structs with trivial dtor and trivial copy-ctor.

Comment: @SergioMartins: It wouldn't, that why you should just use `const T&`. In general this what you want, and it's pointless effort to further modify it to "`const T`" or just "`T`" when you happen to know `T`; the compiler will do this right for you.

Comment: with `const auto&` you signal your intention to not modify anything and that you won't need a copy either. Even if the performance was the same I would go with that because it makes your code more expressive.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: In general the difference between `auto` and `auto&` is subtle, partly a matter of style, but sometimes also a matter of correctness. I am not going to cover the general case here!

In a range based for loop, the difference between

```
for (auto element : container) {}
```

and

```
for (auto& element_ref : container) {}
```

is that `element` is a copy of the elements in the `container`, while `element_ref` is a reference to the elements in the container.

To see the difference in action, consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    int a[5] = { 23,443,16,49,66 };

    for (auto i : a) i = 5;       
    for (const auto& i : a) std::cout << i << std::endl;
    for (auto& i : a) i = 5;   
    for (const auto& i : a) std::cout << i << std::endl;    
}
```

It will print

```
23
443
16
49
66
5
5
5
5
5
```

because the first loop works on copies of the array elements, while the second actually modifies the elements in the array.

If you dont want to modify the elements then often a `const auto&` is more appropriate, because it avoids copying the elements (which can be expensive).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if your vector contains strings. Long strings. 5000 long strings. Copy them unnecessarily and you end up with a nicely written for loop that is awfully inefficient.

Make sure your code follows your intention. If you do not need a copy inside of the loop, do not make one.

Use a reference & as suggested above, or iterators.