# Why BOOST_FOREACH on a map only work with a typedef

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

I tried to write a simple loop through `map<int, int>`element and I'm wondering why the 1st syntax I used doesn't work/compile ?

The 1st version I wrote was the following and it doesn't compile with VS'2008 / boost version 1.44:

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;
...
BOOST_FOREACH(map<int, int>::value_type &p, myMap)
{
}
```

Now if I rewrite the code like below the compilation is ok, but why ?

```
typedef std::map<int, int> myMap_t;
myMap_t myMap;
...
BOOST_FOREACH(myMap_t::value_type &p, myMap)
{
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using C++11 auto instead? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for and http://stackoverflow.com/q/17032267/2436175

Answer (score 12):

It is a preprocessor macro, and it doesn't like the `,` in `map<int, int>`.

Comment: @GIJoe Yes, the answer you linked to uses a typedef for the map, so it doesn't contain the `,`.

Comment: @Angew: Ah, missed that. Good catch