# C++ For Each Loop Printing an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm currently learning programming and learning C++. I'm trying to use the for each loop to print out an array but I'm getting some weird outputs. Here's my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
        int length;
        cin >> length;
        cout << "Enter " << length << " numbers!\n";
        int x[length];  
        for (int i : x){
                cin >> i;
        }
        for (int i : x){
                cout << i << endl;
        }      
        return 0;
}
```

I ran a test and here's my input and output

```
5
Enter 5 numbers!
1
2
3
4
5
78344035
1
2031166200
32767
1528080880
```

If someone could tell me what I did wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: You never wrote any data to the array. You wrote it to the temporary variable i.

Comment: If you don't understand what jacob said, try reading about scopes : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: is `int x[length];` working for you? I thought that would give an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop copies each element of `x` into `i`, and you are streaming into that copy `i` each time:

> ```
> for (int i : x){
>       cin >> i;
> }
> ```

To stream into the array, take each element by reference:

```
for (int& i : x){
            cin >> i;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17032314/1621391)

Again, you are making use of [VLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays)'s which isn't standard C++